# Typo3 - Typoscript set FE username as a constant

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I am currently trying to add the username of the currently logged in FE user as a constant. I have tried the following but it does not seem to work.

```
Username = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
```

I am using [this](http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/cool-stuff-typoscript/userinfo-for-currently-logged-in-user.html) as a starting point

I would like to know how get the FE username into a constant so I can call it when ever I need for the rest of my typoscript.

This is the bit of typoscript that I am trying to get the username into, at the moment it just adds the company name which is defined as a constant else where, but I would like to add int he username also. I have tried adding the global variable for the username but no joy.

```
[usergroup = *]
config.tx_we_google_analytics {
        _setCustomVar = 1, 'Client', '{$companyName} - {TSFE:fe_user|user|username}',2
        }
[end]
```

Many Thanks in Advance

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using an extension to insert something as basic as a Google Analytics Snippet. Each extension slows down the system and makes it less maintainable.

I don't know what your customVar does, but you might try something like

```
temp.analytics = COA
temp.analytics {

  10 = TEXT
  10.value (
    first part of GA snippet
  )

  20 = TEXT
  20.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username

  30 = TEXT
  30.value (
     rest of GA Snippet
  )

}
```

Then insert your snippet where you want, e.g. `headerData.99 < temp.analytics`and you're done.

Or even try with a wrap and insertData=1.

As Artur says, if data doesn't render in .wrap, always try stdWrap.wrap - it tends to add functionality (although afaik there have been efforts to pass every wrap through stdWrap by default, but I don't think it's fully implemented).

Comment: ah, did not even think about just adding it in. I was passed the site for maintenance. But that worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the appropriate global variable inside TypoScript setup directly, there is no need for a constant I think. The example you provided is the global variable I am talking about, which you can use in any getText context inside typoscript setup.

e.g.

```
temp.userName = TEXT
temp.userName.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
```

TypoScript constants allow only direct value assignment, it is not possible to assign any other "variable" to a constant IMHO.

Try this. If you are lucky it could work.

```
[usergroup = *]
config.tx_we_google_analytics {
    _setCustomVar.cObject = TEXT
    _setCustomVar.cObject.value = 1, 'Client', '{$companyName} - {TSFE:fe_user|user|username}',2
    _setCustomVar.cObject.insertData = 1
}
[end]
```

If it doesn't, you will have to modify the plugin code to process the config value by stdWrap. Thsi code works from within the plugin controller

```
$configValue = $this->cObj->stdWrap('',$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['config.']['tx_we_google_analytics.']['_setCustomVar.']);
```

or simpler (stil within the controller)

```
$configValue = $this->cObj->stdWrap('',$this->conf['_setCustomVar.']);
```

Comment: Hi Artur, I have added in the what you have suggested but it is not working. I am most likely doing some thing wrong here as my knowledge of typoscript is somewhat limited. Please have a look at the updated question to see additional code.

Comment: The problem with TypoScript is that it isn't really consistent. I think you can use global variables in object attributes because TYPO3  core pass each attribute to the so called stdWrap function, which evaluates those variables.
To be able to do the same for a simple configuration value of some plugin (tx_we_google_analytics in your case), the author of that plugin must call cObj::stdWrap function explicitly to evaluate potential variables.

Comment: See my updated answer. So this is really a case where it would be useful to assign global variables to constants, but it's not possible.